# Unable to see ToolTip for ComboBox on first attempt

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, tooltip

I am able to create a ComboBox and assign a ToolTip to it with success. However, after I select an item from ComboBox, I need to MouseHover the ComboBox twice to see the ToolTip again. On my first MouseHover attempt, I can not see the ToolTip.

I want my ToolTip to appear on my first attempt as well. Can you please help?

PS: When I assign it to a textbox, it works as I expected.

Reference to CueComboBox: http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/12/01/watermarked-edit-controls/

Thank you

```
public class myClass
{

    ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

    public myClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1;
        toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 5000;
        toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
    }

    void createComboBox()
    {
        CueComboBox generatedCmbBox = new CueComboBox();
        generatedCmbBox.Items.Add("Apple");
        generatedCmbBox.Items.Add("Orange");
        generatedCmbBox.Items.Add("Lemon");
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(generatedCmbBox, "I am a tooltip message");
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(generatedCmbBox, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can remove and add tooltip in `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.comboBox1, "");
    this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.comboBox1, "Some Text");
}
```

Comment: Marking as the accepted answer since it's a working work around. Congratulations on your 20k th rep and thank you.